# Periodic query, do nothing if no change

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

By having the following line in a razor view:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="5">
```

A controller can magically wake up every 5 second and query the database, show the data:

```
return View(myViewModel);
```

But if myViewModel is found to be the same as previous one, I want to do nothing leaving my page as it is (to prevent flicker). How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance. Bob

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)?

- GitHub: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR
- Examples: [Realtime Persistent Long Running Connections With SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)

Comment: I am not sure you are answering my question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't directly. It looks like you want a website that is updated in realtime, and [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) can provide that functionality for you. An alternative would be to do an ajax call using [setTimeout](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/)

Comment: my page can update every 5 second and I am happy about that. Only thing I don't like was that the page is updated even if there is nothing new. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: The only way to stop that is via ajax or a utility such as SignalR. The meta refresh causes a full page reload, hence the flicker. You could potentially have a small ajax call that simply checks for a status, and if there has been an update will then trigger a page refresh using something like `top.location.refresh`